# What is the scope of object which is passed implicitly and returned with its reference?

Tags: c++, oop, reference, scope

I am just trying to overload = operator to copy strings.

```
class cString
{
 int len;
 char *mbuff;
};


int main()
{
cString s1,s2;
s1 = s2;
//here s1 goes out of scope and its destructor called
cout<<" hello";
......
......
......
return 0;
}

cString& cString::operator=(const cString &s)
{
if(this->mbuff!=NULL)
   delete[] (this->mbuff);

this->len = s.len;
this->mbuff = new char[this->len+1];
strcpy(this->mbuff,s.mbuff);
return *this;
}
```

s1=s2 is treated as **s1.operator=(s2);**

In **operator=** function s1 is passed implicitely.
As s1 is created in main's block s1's **destructor** should be called at the end. i.e Just before exiting main.

But If I write return type **cString&(reference)** s1's **destructor** is called immediately after returning from function to main. 
But if return type is **void** it doesn't call s1's **destructor** immediately. It calls normally
while exiting main..

Why does object **s1** go out of scope when I return reference? What's the exact meaning of return *this?

**I know that there is no need to return a reference. I have executed my code successfully with void return type. I am just curious about what might be happening...!**

**Thanks...!**

Comment: Is there any additional content to `str_copy` other than the return?

Comment: does this even compile? str_copy is global, yet there is a *this inside of it

Comment: What is the intention of declaring main as "**void main()" instead of "int main()" ? EDIT: Hmm I guess was some sort of formatting thing this site right? because there is a }** at the end too.

Comment: @Pedrom: I think the intention is BOLD.

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal example demonstrating the problem. `s1`'s destructor should only be called when exiting `main`, regardless of whether you return a reference from `str_copy`. Also, real code contains a lot more semicolons, so it's obvious that you haven't tested the code here.

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks... I just realize something like that after posting the comment :)

Comment: From the edited example... you have several problems since s1 and s2 buffers are being initialized, the operator= would start copying not initialized memory which will end in an undefined behaviour. Is this your actual code? Can you try pasting the actual code you are dealing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that `s1` isn't going out of scope when you think it is. What's going out of scope is almost certainly a temporary object that the compiler helpfully created onyour behalf at some part of the code you didn't show us.

As an aside the valid signatures of `main` never include `void` as the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is incorrect. The scope that has both s1 and s2 is main() [which should be int main()], so they go out of scope at end of main and dtor is called at that point.

The visible part of str_copy does not create or destroy objects so no dtor calls form there. However if it returned cString without reference, That temporary cString would be destroyed at the marked point, and you see a dtor call -- certainly not for s1, but a copy of it.

You might have problems in the part of code not shown.

---

for the edited version: your op= has a ton of problems, including those related to exception safety and self assignment. I suggest using an existing string instead of carving your own broken one consuming time and nerves. And at least read Scott Meyers' Effective C++ that has items on those operators.

Comment: I know that. I am just curious about what might be happening when reference is returned.

Comment: "I suggest using an existing string instead of carving your own broken one consuming time and nerves"... And he will be sure will never learn!

Comment: @Emilio, learning from the "trial and error" method is only good for baron Munchhausen types who can pull themselves from the swamp by hair.  If you want to learn how to implement a working string class, read sources of one, and ask questions on what is not clear.

Comment: @user2151150: It's still unclear how you concluded that dtor is called at the point and for s1. The best bet is still "observation error".

Comment: @BalogPal: I was not taking of "trial and error" and you din't talk about "study a source" (you just said "use"). And frankly, I will never learn anything by reading the `std::string` source, with that tons of `#define` spread around 10 different low level `#include` just to make it work with 10 compiler versions at least.  Tutoring and testing is the key, but there are soooo many fragmented information around that I don't see a way to keep them ordered. Saying "don't do, just use" is like teaching math with a pocket calculator.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: my experience clearly shows how much can be learned by study other's code. and how little is learned by using the keyboard and the debugger. Sure, unfortunately sources like boost are ridden with macros and compiler workarounds so it is struggle, but I still recall learning a lot from shared_ptr implementation.   C++ is full of undefined behavior so just "observing" that something works is no proof. I had to clean up too much of such "work for me" crap to be convinced. :-o

Answer (score 0):

Compare your source with below, this should work

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class cString
{
    public:
    ~cString()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    cString& str_copy(const cString &s)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cString s1,s2;
    s1.str_copy(s2);

    //here s1 should not go out of scope and its destructor called
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\AAA\blah\Debug>blah.exe
hello
destructor
destructor
```

Comment: For an *even* better example, put the code currently in `main` in a new function `do_work()` and have `main` call `do_work` then do a `std::cout << "the work, she is done!" << std::endl;` before returning.